# Looking for approach to prove $\bar{x}$ and $s$ are independent for t-statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given t statistic

$t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{s/\sqrt(n)}$

prove $\bar{x}$ and $s$ are independent...you do not need to prove it...just tell the methods.

One approach that I think of is Let $X = {X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}$ ~ $N_n$, $X_i $are independent.
Let $Y = {Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n}$ ~ $N_n$, $Y_i $are independent.

$\bar{Y} = \sum_{i  = 1}^n Y_i , s^2 = \sum_{i  = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2/ (n-1)$
The general approach is to show that $\bar{Y}$ can be written as a function of $X_1$ and $s^2$ can be written as a function of ${X_2, X_3,..., X_n}$
Since $X_i$ are independent, $\bar{Y}$ and $s^2$are also independent.

What do you think about this approach? Could anyone think of any other approach?

Thank you

Comment: They are not necessarily independent.  For instance, if $x_1,x_2$ are drawn from a Bernoulli distribution and $n=2$ then $\bar x=1/2$ implies that $s^2=(x_1-x_2)^2 =1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you for $n=2$ and under the assumption of normality.

Then $s^2$ is proportional to $(x_1-x_2)^2$ and $\bar x$ to $x_1+x_2$.  Now, $x_1-x_2$ and $x_1+x_2$ are jointly normal, so you only have to check that they are uncorrelated to show that they are independent.  Finally, if $y,z$ are independent then so are $g(y),h(z)$ for any functions $g,h$.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: I do not need the proof ...I just want the approach

Comment: Isn't that what I gave you?

Comment: Just let me know the general case

Comment: The general case works the same.  Just work out these formulas for general $n$ and it becomes very similar; please also note my comment above.

Comment: you told me the approach ... in your comment, you also said they are not necessarily independent....are you contradicting yourself?

Comment: They are independent if the $x_i$'s are normally distributed, but not necessarily if they aren't.

Comment: ok...do you know any other approach?

Comment: if n is infinity ... I will just work with $(x_1 - x_2 - x_3 - ... -x_n)$ right?

Comment: as you said if they are uncorrelated, then they are independent...however, uncorrelated does not guarantee independent though...

Comment: It does if they're jointly normal.

Comment: I think of a new approach...Let $X = {X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}$ ~ $N_n$, $X_i $are independent.
Let $Y = {Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n}$ ~ $N_n$, $Y_i $are independent.

$\bar{Y} = \sum_{i  = 1}^n Y_i , s^2 = \sum_{i  = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2/ (n-1)$
The general approach is to show that $\bar{Y}$ can be written as a function of $X_1$ and $s^2$ can be written as a function of ${X_2, X_3,..., X_n}$
Since $X_i$ are independent, $\bar{Y}$ and $s^2$are also independent. what do you think?